# Where on Earth could I be?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
I lost my toe,  
the foot went grey.  
Where I used to know,  
A hole does stay.  

I found my egg,  
in a ditch was where.  
A root now my leg,  
the trench now a pair.  

I swapped my tree.  
And "oops" in the past,  
(Where could I be?)  
became "ouch" in contrast
```

Where on earth am I?

Hint:

> What I lost sent me from high to something just below
> What I found sent me falling even further though
> What I swapped sent me going between high and low

Hint 2:

> Adding the letter `n` somewhere on the first line would give you a massive clue.

Final Hint:

> It's important that you change your tune or die a critic.

Comment: Does this riddle have anything to do with ROT13(gerapu sbbg be nzchgngvbaf)?

Comment: @Kyle Williamson unfortunately not! it's a bit of a red herring

Comment: rot13(Vg'f ernyyl hasbeghangr gung V nz tbaan qvnpevgvp, orpnhfr V pna'g znxr urnqf be gnvyf bhg bs ynathntrf jvgu nppragf. Vs qvnpevgvp vgfrys vf gur fbyhgvba, V'z tbaan nyfb qvr n pevgvp.)

Comment: @Avi Nice! rot13(Qvnpevgvpf ner na vzcbegnag pbzcbarag gb uryc lbh jvgu gur nafjre! Ohg abg gur nafjre vgfrys!)

Comment: Just wondering why it's common to use rot13 in the comment section?  To avoid spoiler or?

Comment: @Alex Yes, to avoid spoilers

Comment: Does this have to do with rot13(zhfvp abgrf)?

Comment: @KyleWilliamson rot13(Abg rknpgyl zhfvp abgrf ohg vg qbrf vaibyir fbhaq)

Comment: So the n you add in toe is the same as the final hint?

Comment: @Duck rot13(gur svany uvag rkcnaqf ba gur fnzr nern bs uvagvat, ohg lrf gurl ner eryngrq!)

Comment: anything to do with rot13(cvgpu be grag)?

Comment: @Archipelago rot13(cvgpu! ohg abg fb zhpu grag)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know where you are:

> You're in Thailand!

I lost my toe

> Well, you lost your *tone*.

the foot went grey.

> เท้า (foot) เทา (grey - the same characters, just missing a dead critic)

Where I used to know,
A hole does stay.

> Still working on this

I found my egg,
in a ditch was where.

> Don't have this one yet, but ditch and egg have *similar* pronounciations (khu vs khi)

A root now my leg,

> ข่า (galangal, or thai ginger root) ขา (leg)

the trench now a pair.

> คู (trench) คู่ (pair)

I swapped my tree.

> Hmmm, maybe ต้น (tree, kinda) ตน (self)?

And "oops" in the past,
became "ouch" in contrast

> อุ่ย (oops) อุ๊ย (ouch)
>  Awesome riddle, thank you! It was the ouch/oops that gave it away for me, made the clues that it might be to do with a tonal language drop into place.

Comment: Excellent work! You have the answer but there is more to some of the clues. It's worth noting rot13(gurer'f zber gb gur svefg yvar bs rnpu cnentencu. vg freirf nf n zber yvgreny vafgehpgvba).

Comment: You got it. The only part missing was that the traded objects in the riddle are near English homophones of the Thai words for the traded tone marks e.g. my egg (mái èk)